# Check template parameter of Base class in Derived

Tags: c++, function

I have a base class like

```
template <int parameter>
class Base {
public:
  virtual int getMaxParameter() = 0;      
}
```

and I chose one of multiple derived classes like

```
template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
public:
  int getMaxParameter() { return 2; }
}
```

via

```
const int p = 3;
Base<p>* base;
switch (unreleated_input_int) {
  case 1:
    base = new DerivedA<p>(); break;
  case 2:
    base = new DerivedB<p>(); break;
  // ...
}
```

Q: How can I make sure, that the template parameter of Base & Derived does not exceed the return value of getMaxParameter()?

I could do something like

```
DerivedA() {
  if (parameter > getMaxParameter()) 
    //...
}
```

but I don't want to write this in every derived class. Can I do something like this in Base? I can't call pure virtual functions, but is there another way?

I dont need the virtual function, it could be e.g. a member variable of Derived instead.

Comment: I don't really understand your core problem. Do you want to limit the parameter for each derived class separately? I.e. `DerivedA` should limit its parameter to `2`? Why do you use virtual functions for that? In the case the parameter is too large (let's say one instantiates `DerivedA<3>`, do you want to allow that but do nothing in the constructor? (That's your current behavior) Wouldn't it be better to check that during compile time? (That's very easy)

Comment: You say "during runtime I chose to create one of multiple derived classes", that's wrong, you create the class during compile-time ("template instantiation").

Comment: Yes, I want to limit the parameter for each Derived class separately. I'm just looking for the easiest way to do it, I don't need to use that virtual function (it could be e.g. a member variable of Derived instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use a `static_assert` at compile time because the return value of `getMaxParameter` of your derived class is not known yet, you can use a factory...

```
#include <iostream>

template <int parameter>
struct Base {
  void verify () {
    if (parameter > this->getMaxParameter())
      std::cout << "Bigger\n";
    else
      std::cout << "Smaller\n";
  }
  virtual int getMaxParameter() = 0;
};

template <int parameter>
struct Derived : public Base<parameter> {
  virtual int getMaxParameter() { return 0; }
};

template <int parameter>
Base<parameter> * make_and_verify () {
  Base<parameter> * result = new Derived<parameter>;
  result->verify();
  return result;
}

int main() {
  Base<0> * foo = make_and_verify<0>();
  Base<1> * bar = make_and_verify<1>();
  return 0;
}
```

[verified output](http://ideone.com/xErJH2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `static_assert` (a compile-time assertion) to make `DerivedA<3>` (where the condition `3 < 2` is not met) fail compilation (if you like that):

```
template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
    static_assert(parameter < 2, "Parameter for DerivedA is too large!");
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //              condition           message in case of error
public:
};
```

This will give you a nice hint if you write `DerivedA<3>`:

> error: static asertion failed: Parameter for DerivedA is too large!

You could turn `2` into a `constexpr` member. `constexpr` is an indication that it's known during compile-time, which is required for `static_assert`:

```
template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
    static constexpr int maxParameter = 2;
    static_assert(parameter < maxParameter, "Parameter for DerivedA is too large!");
public:
};
```

If you dislike to have this code in each derived class, you can move it to `Base`, which now takes two parameters: the actual parameter and the maximum value. It has the disadvantage that the error message can't include the derived class name, but I guess this is not very important:

```
template <int parameter, int maxParameter>
class Base
{
    static_assert(parameter < maxParameter, "Parameter is too large!");
};

template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter, 2> 
{
};
```

If you don't like the second template parameter for the `Base` class (like it is the problem in your added factory code in your question), you can move it to the `Base` constructor. It's a bit tricky to invoke the templated constructor, [but possible with the help of template type deduction and a dummy parameter](http://ideone.com/qyQjr2):

```
template <int parameter>
class Base
{
public:
    template <int maxParameter>
    Base(std::integral_constant<int, maxParameter>) {
        static_assert(parameter < maxParameter, "Parameter is too large!");
    }
};

template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
public:
    DerivedA() : Base(std::integral_constant<int, 2>()) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you, great answer. However, I added an example of my call for the Derived constructors (which I should have mentioned earlier), and I can't get it to work with that.

Comment: I'm sorry but why doesn't my solution work then? The *class* is created at compile time, *instances* (objects) are of course still created during runtime. When looking at your added code, the only problem I see with my solution is that you now can't assign a `Derived<p>*` to `Base<p>*` because of the added template parameter. But that can be fixed easily...

Answer (score 0):

The class is created at **compile time** as a template instantiation.

The best you can do is a `static_assert` is the value to be checked against is a constexpr :

```
template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
public:
  static_assert(parameter < 2, "wrong template parameter value");

  int getMaxParameter() { return 2; }
};
```

Or, assuming you can make `getMaxParameter` a `constexpr` :

```
template <int parameter>
class DerivedA : public Base<parameter> 
{
public:
  constexpr int getMaxParameter() { return 2; }
  static_assert(parameter < getMaxParameter(), "wrong template parameter");
};
```

Comment: Thank you! But my problem turned out to be different: I've just added a piece of code where I create my Derived classes. As all of them seem to be created at compile time, your (and leemes) approach doesn't seem to work.